# how can a plastic comb be charged up if it is an insulator of electricity?

Tags: electricity

If I take a plastic comb and rub it against dry hair it attracts tiny bits of paper and on other hand plastic is a poor conductor of electricity and does not allow electric charge to flow through it easily,so how come it is being charged up  by rubbing????

Comment: have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Cause

Comment: An insulator means that a current cannot be set up within it, there is no motion of charges, ions or electrons, they are tied in the lattice. Individual ions and electrons can be created, but no drift velocity within the insulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object is called charged negative when it has extra electrons and positive if it has not enough electron. Both cases are compared with the case in which the object has as much electrons as it has protons.

Now If you rub plastic comb against dry hair, electrons are removed from comb and added to dry hair. The reason for this phenomenon is related to atomic scaled physical properties. It needs quantum knowledge to figure out  why exactly does this electron removal happen.

Let's accept this removal and addition of electrons and say its the nature of those kind of materials.

When an amount of charge is put on the surface of a poor conductor, it will stay there (as you said "poor conductor") until we put the surface in contact with something else that absorbs the extra charge. And this *is* happening when we do it. The object is always in contact with air and randomly loses its extra charge. Finally it gets very close to the neutral state. But it may not be the previous purely neutral one.

Now, If we know that the surface of an object is charged, then that charge produces electric field around it. This is again the nature of charge. Charge makes others aware of its existence there, by its field around itself.

If another poor conductor is placed in that electric field, going down to atomic scale, we see that the center of the electron cloud around nucleus isn't on it any longer. we see a "separation". That's because + charges move in the opposite direction of - charges' movement and thus get farther from each other.

If this separation happens, we say the paper has been "polarized" and thus acts like an electric dipole.

The induced electric dipole moment is always in the direction of the field. Thus the dipole is forced to move in the opposite direction of the field. That is, in the direction to the comb.

So they stick to each other. And because of the exchange of electron between comb and paper, the charge of comb is reduced, so it can no longer hold the paper. So bits of paper fall.

From the "dipole" part on, for you to get fully convinced, you will need some mathematics. Read Griffith's Introduction to electrodynamics for more technical reasoning. But I'm sure it will take very much. that's it. More questions, more effort to find the answers!